# Property storage name warning

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

After executing multiple data from excel sheet it display warning message

Warning:  Property storage name for 5 is empty - setting to Root Entry.

Can some one please explain why this warning comes.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to you are using xls Excel 97-2003 file, Just modify your file as ".xlsx" i.e. excel2007 file format (xlsx).